# Can I change width of tmux tabs?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I'm trying to find out a solution to change the width of the tabs (or what it's called in the tmux world). I can't seem to find an option for it. Is it possible?

Ideally they would have flexible width, like they do now, but increase the ma width (so that I can see the entire path in the screenshot). If it's not possible, a solution with fixed with could also work.

[image]

Comment: See `status-left/right-length`

Comment: Isn't that just for the elements on the left/right side? And not the individual tabs?

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to by "tabs"...

Comment: @jasonwryan I think he means "pane". The different parts that a window is divided into. But I'm not sure. He might just be meaning the info area?

Comment: @Kusalananda Ah. Resize pane: `C/Alt-Left/Right`.

Comment: @jasonwryan Sorry I wasn't being clear enough. Updated the screenshot with a circle. This is what I'm referring to as "tabs".

Comment: That's the status line: see my first comment.

Comment: @jasonwryan Are you shure? I tried changing them, but didn't make any difference. I found that I can change the number of characters displayed with this: `set-option -gw window-status-format " #I:#{=16:window_name} "`, but I was only able to make it shorter. It looks like 16 characters is a maximum. If I set it above 16, it always stays at 16, but if I change it to less, then the length is reflected to the number.

Answer (score 1):

## Print path basename as window name.

This will just make the text more manageable because it is smaller.  It might work for what you are looking at doing.

### Tmux

- tmux 2.9a

Example bash script that reads #{pane_current_path) arg.  `basename` truncates the beginning path and just displays current.  This is nice if using as a window id.

### ~/.tmux_path.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
printf '\033%s\007' $(basename $1) # show full path use $1 instead of $(basename $1)
```

### Make script executable

```bsh
chmod +x ~/.tmux_path.sh
```

### ~/.tmux.conf

```bsh
set -g status-interval 1
set -g window-status-current-format "[#[fg=white] #(~/.tmux_path.sh #{pane_current_path})]"
set -g window-status-format "#[fg=black] #(~/.tmux_path.sh #{pane_current_path})"
```